Using past perfect in one or both clauses
Which version is correct? Do I need to use past perfect in both clause or once is enough?

I was happy I hadn't done it when she arrived

I was happy I hadn't done it when she had arrived



I'm not sure exactly what you want to say here (you should explain the full context and intended meaning, rather that just presenting a couple of texts and asking which is "best"). But almost certainly, your context is one where native speakers would say I was glad [that some situation came about].

...but as ever, you should avoid unnecessary repetition of perfect verb forms.

We can use the past perfect to indicate an event happening before a certain time in the past.
(1) is fine.  Your doing (in past perfect) precedes her arrival (in simple past).
In (2), both the doing and her arrival are in past perfect and hence wouldn’t work.
